# Increase in authorization permission errors - Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console, google-crawlers

"Increase in authorization permission errors "

I have been getting this error for the past 2 nights in webmasters tools for one of my sites, the only change I have made that I think could contribute to this error is with my robots.txt file.

This is it:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow:

User-agent: bingbot
Disallow:

User-agent: Yahoo-slurp
Disallow:

User-agent: Msnbot
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This robots file validates and in webmasters I ran a test to see if google can crawl pages and it says the googlebot is allowed at line 5 (which is correct) but im just wondering if the

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

at the bottom is overriding the command for Googlebots?

Before I started getting this error, I placed

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

above all the bot specific commands - but it didn't validate, but also-- I didn't get the 
"Increase in authorization permission errors"  error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

That's what causing the crawl blocks.